# Spinner graphical bug API 21

Tags: android, spinner, visual-glitch

I have one spinner in a fragment that have a very annoying graphical glitch.
This occurs only on my Nexus 5 with API 21.
[image]

I have try to set spinner.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null) but the glitch is still present.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have to open a bug report in this case and forza italia :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to work around this bug in two different ways:

1. Set a style to your spinner:

   ```
   <Spinner
       android:background="@drawable/background"
       android:id="@+id/spinner"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"/>
   ```

maybe the background color in the predefined styles is enough for you. If not try

2. Create a shape drawable with a corner radius:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
       <corners android:radius="2dp" />
       <solid android:color="#00ff00" />
   </shape>
   ```

and set it as a popupBackground to your spinner

```
    <Spinner
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
        android:id="@+id/date_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/spinner_popup_background"/>
```

hope this is helpful!

Comment: Many thanks PaMaDo!!!! My problem is that I use android:popupBackground with a color