# Changing Spinner background generates dark colored border

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

Using a simple spinner. When I scroll the spinner **the shadow** around spinner dropdown starts **growing darker in color**.

I managed to fix the issue but

> I will appreciate if someone could explain me why was this
>   happening?

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@id/drop_list_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dropDownSelector="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
            android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/min_header_height"
            android:popupBackground="#FFFFFF" />
```

[image: The dropdown list of spinner]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed: for Api below 21

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown"
```

if working on api 21 and above

```
android:popupTheme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown"
```

Answer (score 2):

As of July 2016, the shadowing issue is still present when `android:popupBackground` is used to specify a color (eg: White)

Google has provided a fix for this for Android 6.0 and above via `android:popupTheme` but that is not applicable for < 6.0

Detailed explanation : [How do I set a different theme for a Spinner's dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066277/how-do-i-set-a-different-theme-for-a-spinners-dropdown/32066279#32066279)

Working Solution (Android < 6.0) - Creating a shape and using it as background : [Spinner graphical bug API 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013120/spinner-graphical-bug-api-21/28836851#28836851)

Comment: Thank you i removed the PopupBackground after that it was working.