# How do I set a different theme for a Spinner's dropdown?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

An example usage:

[image]

The Spinner is dark themed, but I want the dropdown to be light themed.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

**Android M**

New in Android 6.0, Spinner now has the `android:popupTheme` parameter which allows you to set the theme used for the popup (dropdown).

You can use it as so:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light" />
```

That will work on devices running API level 23+, but not on devices running a lower version of Android.

**AppCompat**

This is where AppCompat comes in. Its Spinner implementation also supports `popupTheme`, but it's a bit more involved to get right.

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

After that, you need to update your Adapter to be able to work with AppCompat. You do that by making it implement the new [`ThemedSpinnerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ThemedSpinnerAdapter.html) interface.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ThemedSpinnerAdapter {

   Theme getDropDownViewTheme() { ... }

   void setDropDownViewTheme(Theme theme) { ... }

}
```

These methods are used by Spinner to be able to tell the Adapter which theme to use for inflating any drop down views. To make this as easy as possible we have given you a [`Helper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ThemedSpinnerAdapter.Helper.html) class which you can plug in to your adapter.

This means that your adapter becomes something like:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ThemedSpinnerAdapter {
  private final ThemedSpinnerAdapter.Helper mDropDownHelper;

  public MyAdapter(Context context) { 
    mDropDownHelper = new ThemedSpinnerAdapter.Helper(context);
  }

  @Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;

    if (convertView == null) {
      // Inflate the drop down using the helper's LayoutInflater
      LayoutInflater inflater = mDropDownHelper.getDropDownViewInflater();
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dropdown, parent, false);
    }

    // ...

    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void setDropDownViewTheme(Theme theme) {
    mDropDownHelper.setDropDownViewTheme(theme);
  }

  @Override
  public Theme getDropDownViewTheme() {
    return mDropDownHelper.getDropDownViewTheme();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I couldn't find ThemedSpinnerAdapter inside the appcompat-v7. I'm using version 22.2.1. Do I have to do anything different to import it?

Comment: @DouglasAlves use newest 23.0.0

Comment: It seems Android Studio doesn't know about the app:popupTheme Spinner attribute: "Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag Spinner". Lint also fails with the same error.

Comment: @Chris Banes : It gives the drop down list with a dark background, irrespective of the theme you use.

Comment: @Chris Banes : I put a break point inside setDropDownViewTheme(). But it never reaches there. That means setDropDown() is never being called.

Comment: should it use "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner" instead of "spinner"  in the xml?

Comment: Seems this work for a dropdown style spinner but not for spinnerMode="dialog". For a dialog it wont change the theme.  Is there really a way to change the appearance of that dialog?

Comment: Last example looks awfully similar to the Android Docs :}

Comment: The spinner jumps around when scrolling with a theme set. Very annoying.

Comment: There is a bug specifically in the `AppCompat` version `app:popupTheme`. When I use `android:popupTheme`, it __does__ work correctly (without jumping around).

Answer (score 2):

for **spinner's arrow** I've used `android:backgroundTint="@color/white"` this will work from API 21

for spinner view and dropdown view:

```
ArrayAdapter<Area> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Area>(getContext(),R.layout.spinner_item, areas);

areasAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.dropdwon_item);
areasSpinner.setAdapter(areasAdapter);
```

for **getView()** the adapter will use spinner_item.xml

for **getDropDownView()** the adapter will use dropdwon_item.xml

then you can use your custom layouts as you like

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference if you use the `CursorAdapter` your implementation can be much easier, just override `newView()`, no need to override `getDropDownView()` there:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mDropDownHelper.getDropDownViewInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

you can try this:
in your layout folder make a spinner_item.xml:

```
<TextView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background = "#ffffff"
android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal" />
```

then use this code:

```
spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(R.layout.spinner_item,items);
```

Comment: I guess because it's fairly obvious it doesn't answer the question. The question is about setting a theme, I see no reference to theming in this answer. Just so we're clear, I didn't downvote this, others have gone at it enough already.